# What is the difference between "even better", "much better", and "a lot better" in comparison statements?

Tags: adverbs, comparison

In comparison statements, you can use "even" or "much" (or "a lot") to emphasize the degree of the adjective or adverb.

However, is there any difference between "even", "much", an "a lot"?

For example:

> I can swim faster than he.
>
> I can swim even faster than he.
>
> I can swim a lot faster than he.
>
> I can swim much faster than he.

What is the difference?

Comment: It's just a question of degrees.  There is the comparison to the prior statement (all of these increase speed relatively), and then there is the degree of how much faster.  "even faster" implies a larger degree of speed difference, "a lot faster" moreso and "much faster" even moreso.  The differences aren't quantified, they're just general and relative.  You're 50 and I'm 51? I'm a little older than you.  You're 20?  I'm a lot older or much older than you.

Comment: @JimMacKenzie So if you order them by the degree, it is - much > a lot > even > nothing - ?

Comment: Yes, assuming they're all comparing to the same base amount.

Comment: In my opinion, "much" and "a lot" are the same.

Comment: I agree that "much" and "a lot" mean the same here. I also agree with Amber Hopkins' point in her answer - that "even faster" doesn't necessarily mean that there's a big gap in speed between the two swimmers.  Rather it means that one of the swimmers is fast, and the other (even) faster (but not necessarily by a large amount).  It's worth noting than in real life we rarely say "faster than he".  It is usually either "faster than him" or "faster than he can".

Answer (score 1):

**Much** and **a lot** mean pretty much the same thing in those sentences: there is a significant difference between the two things.

**Even more** does not tell you whether it is only a little more or a lot more, but it is usually used when comparing to something that has a great or low value.  In your example, the 'he' in question is probably a very fast swimmer.

*Even* can also be used when something increases or decreases in value:

"I have even more homework to do by Friday!" or "I have even less money now than I did last year"